# Struggling with Python Regex for a very specific array

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a regex method (if you can find an easier method, please tell)

For example: I need the lines that are marked with "!" at the end

```
[ExpertSingle]
{
192 = N 0 0
384 = N 0 0
576 = N 0 0
768 = N 0 0
960 = N 0 0
}
```

**Edit**: replaced with actual data

Answer (score 1):

You could just find the lines that with one or more numbers

```
import re
inputStr = """[ExpertSingle]
{
192 = N 0 0
270 = N 1 0
270 = N 2 0
360 = N 0 0
}"""

goodLines = re.findall(r"\d+.+", inputStr)
print(goodLines)
```

This outputs: `['192 = N 0 0', '270 = N 1 0', '270 = N 2 0', '360 = N 0 0']`

If you wanted to be ultra strict and only find words in the format of some digits, a space, an equals, a space, a letter, a space, a digit, a space, then another digit you could use

```
goodLines = re.findall(r"\d+\s=\s\w\s\d\s\d", inputStr)
```

Comment: The lines dont actually end in "!" that's just an indicator to make it easier to find what data I need. And not all of them end in 0 or contain " = N" as some may be " = S "

Comment: @whamer100 so post your real data and i'll edit it. Don't give me some data and then tell me "by the way that's not the actual data"

Comment: I replaced the data